# How do I get / transfer value from Javascript to PHP variable (it has checked "no" in radio button) in different page?

Tags: php, javascript, hyperlink, radio-button

How do I get / transfer value from JavaScript to PHP variable (it has checked "no" in radio button) in different page?

For example my script on JavaScript:

```
<script language="Javascript">
    function getReject(){
var RadioButton = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); 
var Reject = confirm("Deny?");
for (var i = 0; i < RadioButton.length; i++) 
{ 
    if (RadioButton[i].type == "radio" && Reject) 
    { 
        if(RadioButton[i].checked && RadioButton[i].value != "yes"){
            alert("The data will be transferred back to the owner");
            window.location ='deny.php?menu_id=<?=$menu_id?>';
            return true;
        }
    }
}
}
<script>
```

The HTML:

```
<td align='center' class='tablecontent' valign='top'><input type='radio' id='yes' name='chk$num' value='yes' checked='checked'></td>
<td align='center' class='tablecontent' valign='top'><input type='radio' id='no' name='chk$num' value='no'></td>
```

Below of the alert in the Javascript there is a link (window.location) going to a new page, that is deny page.

First, when I choose / click "no" on the radio button, in the javascript will show up alert that is `alert("The data will be transferred back to the owner");`,
Second, when that alert show up then click ok, I want to direct go to the link `window.location ='deny.php?menu_id=<?=$menu_id?>';`. 
In this deny page, I would like to update to database that status is 'Deny' (after done click "no" on the radio button).

I don't know how to get / transfer value from JavaScript to PHP variable (in deny page).

Comment: what is the value of $menu_id,where it is coming from ,where it is defined

Comment: The value of $menu_id is a number, it's coming from a database.

Comment: Oh anyway, I've figured out what the problem is :).
Thanks for your care, Sumit.